# Build meteor app with cordova on Ubuntu

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build my Meteor app for Android on Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is that the command

```
meteor build '~/MeteorApp' --server=http://myIP
```

yields the error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp':Uh oh!                          
"~/MeteorApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/com/meteor/webapp/WebAppLocalServer.java" already exists!
```

A friend of mine did the same on his Mac and he has no such problems so I am not sure if it might be due to Ubuntu... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you emptied your `~/MeteorApp` folder before building?

If this is the folder where you have your Meteor project source, you should try specifying a different output folder for the `build` command.

Finally, Meteor sometimes struggles in re-installing Codova plugins (and systematically if you change the app name). Simply deleting the `.meteor/local/codova-build` folder entirely and letting Meteor re-building it from scratch is enough most of the time.